# What is the test for endometriosis?

Tags: pain, gynecology, diagnosis, menstrual-cycle, endometriosis

My girlfriend, who is 44 and never had kids, has very severe pain and cramps during her period. Her gynaecologist just gives her pain killers.
What tests should she do to figure out if she has endometriosis?

Comment: I live in Canada so they try to avoid costly tests diagnostic tests such as MRI's and laparoscopys, unfortunately. However, I was exhibiting the same symptoms as your girlfriend  (I'm only 28), and he suspected I had endometriosis just based on my symptoms and said that regardless of what the cause is, the treatment would still be the same -- a hormonal IUD (inter-uterine-device). He prescribed me Minera and inserted into my uterus. It also works as a contraption and is effective for up to five years and is said to eliminate periods completely. She should speak to her OBGYN abt Minera.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common ways to diagnose endometriosis are as follows:

- Palpation/physical exam
- Imaging test (MRI, Ultrasound)
- Laparoscopy*

Laparoscopy, where the doctor makes a small incision to insert a camera tube into the pelvic area for a visual examination, is the only definitive way to diagnose endometriosis. In each case, the doctor is looking for cysts or scars outside the uterus, due to tissue (endometrium) growing where it shouldn't.

If you suspect that she has this, I would suggest talking to her doctor and asking specifically about exams to rule it out, especially given her age and pain during menstruation. (I would also suggest it if the pain is new. If she has had painful menstruation all her life, it's less likely but still can't be ruled out.)

http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Endometriosis/Pages/Diagnosis.aspx

http://www.womenshealth.gov/publications/our-publications/fact-sheet/endometriosis.html